# How to do string splitting

Tags: powershell

How can I split a string?

I would like to turn `C:\RoamingFiles\D\file.txt` to `D:\file.txt`.

I'm not sure how to do it, as split won't filter out `C:\RoamingFiles\` as I want.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm a little confused as to what exactly you want `-split` to do here. It seems like

```
$myString -replace '^C:\\RoamingFiles\\([^\\]+)\\', '$1:\'
```

would work better for what you seem to be doing there. This essentially replaces the path component `C:\RoamingFiles\` with the drive letter that follows. But this is all pretty much guesswork since you gave only one example.

Comment: This regex cant handle 8-letters paths. (for example c:\PROGRA~1\). can you please fix the code? thanks.

Comment: So it's not always in C:\RoamingFiles\?

Comment: That was an example. my actual path is $env:Temp\LC

Answer (score 1):

Tried this use [System.IO.Path]?

```
$name = "C:\RoamingFiles\file.txt"
$shortname =  [System.IO.Path]::GetFileName($name)
$newname =  [System.IO.Path]::Combine("D:\", $shortname)
echo $newname
```

Comment: its not always D. the drive is the first directory in C:\RoamingFiles

Answer (score 0):

This should work just fine (including sub-folders):

```
$fullPath = "C:\RoamingFiles\D\test\test2\file.txt"
$baseFolder = "C:\RoamingFiles\" -replace "\\", "\\"
$fullPath -match "$baseFolder([a-z]\\.+)" | Out-Null
Write-Host $matches[1].Insert(1, ":")
```